# How to generate list of 50 random numbers (between 0 and 100) in FreePascal

Tags: list, sequence, freepascal

Can someone help me to generate list of 50 random numbers (between 0 and 100) in FreePascal?

Comment: Yes, the official FreePascal documentation.

Comment: @H2CO3 There was only random function, but I didn't find about list of random numbers.

Comment: Create a loop that executes 50 times, in the loop generate a random number and insert it into your list.

Comment: @JohnSmith For that, you have to come up with an algorithm.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, but how can I insert generated number into the list? Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of list you are using, so it is hard to say.

Comment: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tlist.html There seems to be an Add method, that is probably a good place to start. TList is a list of pointers, if you don't know what that means you should read up on pointers, or choose a different storage method.

Comment: see http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,19391.0.html

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to have an array of 50 integers, you can use the following code. First it initializes the random number generator by using [`Randomize`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/randomize.html) procedure. Then it iterates the array from its low index to its high index (instead, you might use constant range `for I := 0 to 49 to` as well), and for each element of that array generates a random number in a range of 0 to 100 by using the [`Random`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/random.html) function. The [`Random`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/random.html) function returns a random number which is greater or equals to 0 and is less than the only parameter that this function takes:

```
var
  I: Integer;
  IntArray: array[0..49] of Integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  for I := Low(IntArray) to High(IntArray) do
    IntArray[I] := Random(101);
  ...
end;
```